# Testing alarm on setRepeating without waiting 24 hrs

Tags: android, service

I've setup two service alarms to use setRepeating at different intervals. Alarm A activates and repeats at 9am. Alarm B stops Alarm A service and repeats every 12pm. This seemed to work (with patience) for three days in a row starting and stopping the service, but this morning the test didn't work.

Without a debugger I'm not sure how I can see the logs to determine what went wrong. I'd also like to be able to test the alarms without waiting for the 24 hour intervals. Is this possible?  And is anyone familiar with services not starting and stopping consistently?

Comment: "Without a debugger I'm not sure how I can see the logs to determine what went wrong" -- a debugger is not used to look at LogCat, or to use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to examine the outstanding alarms. "I'd also like to be able to test the alarms without waiting for the 24 hour intervals. Is this possible?" -- use an emulator and set the time in the emulator ahead through the Settings app.

Comment: Thanks for this. The settings app works on the emulator and live device both as expected. I tried the `adb shell dumpsys alarm` command and noticed a lot of pending alarms (most originating from the calendar). Is there a point where these alarms can exhaust memory?

Comment: "Is there a point where these alarms can exhaust memory?" -- not that I am aware of.